# Insert a row in to google BigQuery table from the values of a python list

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am a newbie who is exploring Google BigQuery. I would like to insert a row into the BigQuery table from a python list which contains the row values.

To be more specific my list looks like this: [100.453, 108.75, 50.7773]

I found a couple of hints from [BigQuery-Python library insert](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python#inserting-data) 
and also looked in to [pandas bigquery writer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-bigquery-writer) but not sure whether they are perfect for my usecase.

What would be the better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with Google Cloud Platform services using Python, I would recommend using **python [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/)** and for BigQuery specifically the submodule [google-cloud-bigquery](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html)(this was also recommended by @polleyg. This is an open-source Python idiomatic client maintained by the Google. This will allow you to easily use all the google cloud services in a simple and consistent way.

More specifically, the example under `Insert rows into a table’s data` in the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html) shows how to insert Python tuples/lists into a BigQuery table.

However depending on your needs, you might need other options, my ordering of options:

1. If the you use code that has a **native interface** with Google Services (e.g. BigQuery) and this suits your needs, use this. In your case test if [Pandas-BigQuery](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-bigquery-writer) works for you.
2. If your current code/modules don't have a native interface, try the **Google maintained idiomatic client** [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/).
3. If that doesn't suit your needs, use an **external idiomatic client** like [tylertreat/BigQuery-Python](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python#inserting-data). The problem is that you will have different inconsistent clients for the different services. The benefit can be that it adds some functionalities not provided in the [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) module.
4. Finally, if you work with very *new alpha/beta* features, use the **APIs directly with the [Google API module](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)**, this is will always give you access to the latest APIs, but is a bit harder to work with. So only use this if the previous options don't give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Fematich for the elaborative list of resources. My main intention was to know on how I can insert the values from the "Python list" in to a row in the BigQuery table. With respect to the libraries you mentioned, to insert a row, the data should be in a JSON format but in my condition I am dealing with a "Python list". This is adding an extra effort for every iteration to convert the data.

Comment: Did you try the example under `Insert rows into a table’s data` in the [google-cloud-bigquery docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html)? That shows an example using Python tuples/lists.

Comment: Hello @fematich, I already tried it, but not successful in inserting it as it turned to be working erroneously for which I have updated the Google team on. Regret for the late response.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with "Insert rows into a table’s data"  with google cloud bigquery module, so that I can accept your answer. For your information, I have recently received a response from google team that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I just changed my response.

Comment: FYI, google-cloud-bigquery is incompatible with Google App Engine. Instead, you must use the poorly documented Jobs Insert API.

Answer (score 11):

Lot's of resources but I usually find code examples to be the most informative for beginning.

Here's an excellent collection of bigquery python code samples: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/tree/master/samples.

One straight forward way to insert rows:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
table = bq_client.get_table("{}.{}.{}".format(PROJECT, DATASET, TABLE))

rows_to_insert = [{u"COL1": 100.453, u"COL2": 108.75, u"COL3": 50.7773}, {u"COL1": 200.348, u"COL2": 208.29, u"COL3": 60.7773}]

errors = bq_client.insert_rows_json(table, rows_to_insert)
if errors == []:
    print("success")
```

Lastly to verify if it's inserted successfully [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748871/unable-to-insert-data-into-bigquery-table):

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'SELECT * FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE`'
```

Hope that helps everyone!

Comment: thank you! 
more explicit example: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/master/samples/table_insert_rows.py

Answer (score 0):

The Google BigQuery docs show you how:

1. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_stream_data_python
2. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/stream_data.py