# Unable to insert data into BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to insert record to BigQuery using my Python Code. I always get Table not found error even though table exist.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
key_path = service-account.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project=credentials.project_id,
)
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('mydataset')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('mytable3')
rows_to_insert = [(u'Adam', 32),(u'Eve', 29)]
errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)
assert errors == []
```

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./insert.py", line 24, in <module>
    bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
  File "/Users/adam/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 581, in get_table
    api_response = self._call_api(retry, method="GET", path=table_ref.path)
  File "/Users/adam/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 476, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/Users/adam/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 277, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/Users/adam/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/adam/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 393, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET 
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/datasets/mydataset/tables/mytable3: Not found: Table myproject:mydataset.mytable3
```

I am inserting values at Thu Nov  7 13:23:10 CET 2019 and table was created on 7 Nov 2019, 11:02:48 (after 2 hrs). Is there any reason I am getting table not found, even though the table is visible in GUI and CLI both.

Comment: errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(**table**, rows_to_insert)  This **table** variable is not defined in your posted code snippet

Comment: Could you go to here to test on right side whether the rest api works? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get

Comment: dataset and table names are case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you are sharing, I see that the [BigQuery API call](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html?highlight=get_table#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.get_table) `table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)` is missing. You can employ the following script to insert values in an already existing table named `TABLE` created in the dataset `DATASET`

```
from google.cloud import bigquery                                                                                                                                                  
from google.oauth2 import service_account                                                                                                                                          

key_path = "./service-account.json"                                                                                                                                                
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(                                                                                                               
   key_path,                                                                                                                                                                      
   scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],                                                                                                                     
)                                                                                                                                                                                  

def insert_to_bigquery(rows_to_insert, dataset_name="DATASET", table_name="TABLE"):                                                                                           
   # Instantiates a client                                                                                                                                                        
   bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()                                                                                                                                            

   # Prepares a reference to the dataset and table                                                                                                                                
   dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)                                                                                                                            
   table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)                                                                                                                                      
   # API call                                                                                                                                                                     
   table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)                                                                                                                                   

   # API request to insert the rows_to_insert                                                                                                                                     
   errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)                                                                                                                    
   assert errors == []                                                                                                                                                            

rows_to_insert = [( u'Jason', 32),\                                                                                                                                                
                 ( u'Paula', 29),\                                                                                                                                                
                 (u'Hellen', 55)]                                                                                                                                                 

insert_to_bigquery(rows_to_insert)
```

One can test that the insertion of values was successful by running the following [`bq`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) command:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'SELECT * FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE`'
```